# Spring injecting from Yaml configs

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, yaml

I am currently having an issue when trying to inject values from a Yaml config file into my java class.

I am trying to inject values into a Map, typeAuthorizer is an object I wrote.

I only need the UUID since I plan to instantiate the objects in my code through a Data-factory class.

This is what it looks like:

Table:

```
@Autowired
private Map<UUID, TypeAuthorizer> typeAuthorizers;
```

Yaml Config:

```
typeAuthorizers:

   -
    UUID: "48ec2eaf-890f-43fa-a9de-5af32be6eea2"

    typeAuthorizer: null
```

When I load my main class, I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.eaio.uuid.UUID]
```

Is there a way to define a method for injecting each entry in the map? Or any other kind of work arounds?

is there a way to get spring to instantiate objects using a Factory class that you define for it in the yaml file and then put it into the map?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you treat UUID as a String in the map instead does it work?

Comment: Yes it works, thanks